# css browser compatibility firefox not working

Tags: css, browser

I am working on a new website, but when my friend tested it on firefox one of the features was not working.

We found out the css is not working in firefox but it does work in Chrome.

The whole code: https://jsfiddle.net/wvkL6d2b/

We tried 
-webkit- and -ms-

```
 #separator{      width: 10px!important; max-width: 60px!important; height: 10px; background:red;}

  @keyframes in-out {
         from { width: 10px;
        }
              10%, 100% {
                  width: 60px;
              }
        to{ width: 60px; }
    }
  #separator {
        animation-name: in-out;
      animation-duration: 8s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-delay: 2s;
      }
```

I am trying to get it to work on both browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many mistakes in the CSS properties you have written. Please find the updated code here in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rg6fawpt/2/).
 These are supposed to be properties to use.

```
 #separator {
   height: 10px;
   background: red;
   -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
 }

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  0% { width: 10px; }
  100% { width: 100px; }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
  0% { width: 10px; }
  100% { width: 100px; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you have declared the wrong property.

The declaration you need for firefox is just animation. Only Chrome and Safari need the -webkit- prefix for this CSS3 effect.

So your code would be:

```
-webkit-animation:slideshow 21s infinite;

animation:slideshow 21s infinite;
```

**Ref:**
http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp

Comment: Thanks for your quick respond but its not working I already have the same code here (  https://jsfiddle.net/wvkL6d2b  )

Comment: That's not correct, animation is just a shortcode for the other properties.